# What is the probability that either $A$ or $B$ but not both will occur?

Tags: probability

Events $A$ and $B$ are defined on a sample space $S$ such that $P((A\cup B)^c)=0.5$ and $P(A\cap B) = 0.2$. What is the probability that either $A$ or $B$ but not both will occur?

I have tried using Venn diagrams to solve the problem but I have been unsuccessful so far. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: $P(A\cup B) = P(A\cap B^c) + P(A^c \cap B) + P(A\cap B)$ while $$P(\mathrm{exactly~one~of }~A~\mathrm{and}~B~\mathrm{occurs}) = P(A\cap B^c) + P(A^c \cap B).$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You are looking for the probability of an event $(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$.

---

**Sum** of events $A\cup B$ contains all outcomes for which *at least one* of $A,B$ occurs while the **intersection** $A \cap B$ - those for which both $A$ *and* $B$ do.

Since the difference of $E$ and $F$ is a set of outcomes for which (at the same time) $E$ occurs but $F$ does not (i.e. $E\setminus F= E\cap F^c$), the set for which at least one $A$ or $B$ but not both hold is exactly $(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$.

Comment: ok so that would be .5/.2. but what is the significance of that event, can someone explain?

Comment: Let me ask if I understand your calculation correctly: what is the probability of $\mathbb{P}(E\setminus F)$ in terms of $\mathbb{P}(E)$ and $\mathbb{P}(F)$, whenever $F$ is a subset of $E$?

Comment: P(E/F) would be different from P(E)/P(F)

Comment: Notice that $0.5/0.2$ exceeds $1$, in particular it can't be the probability of any event. I suggest you to look at the Venn diagram of $E$ and $F$ when $F \subset E$ and to think of a probability as a measure of those sets. One should expect $\mathbb{P}(E)=\mathbb{P}(F)+\mathbb{P}(E\setminus F)$ to hold in this case. And indeed it can be easily derived from Kolmogorov axioms.

Comment: it would be 0.3 right?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really great with probability notations but If I may share a very handy formula for problems like this.

Let P(A), P(B) be proabability representing occurence of events A and B, respectively. 
 P(A ***or*** B) is the probability that *either* or *both of*  A and B occur. 
 P(A ***and*** B), both A and B occur. 
P(A ***or*** B)**'**, *neither* of A and B occurs. This is just the complement of P(A ***or*** B). 
 P(A ***xor*** B), probability that either A or B will occur **but not both!**

First basic equation:

> P(A ***or*** B) = P(A) $+$ P(B) $-$ P(A ***and*** B)

$1$ $-$ P(A ***or*** B)**'** = P(A) $+$ P(B) $-$ P(A ***and*** B) 
$1$ $-$ $0.5$ = P(A) $+$ P(B) $-$ $0.2$ 
$\therefore$ P(A) $+$ P(B) = $0.7$

Second basic equation:

> P(A ***xor*** B) = P(A) $+$ P(B) $-$ $2\times$P(A *and* B)

P(A ***xor*** B) = $0.7 - 2\times0.2$ 
$\therefore$ P(A ***xor*** B) = $0.3$

**answer:** $0.3$

Answer (score 0):

The Venn diagram method will work fine.

Draw the usual two intersecting ovals, and label them $A$ and $B$.

You can see $A\cap B$ in the picture. It is the region in common between $A$ and $B$. We are told that $\Pr(A\cap B)=0.2$. Write $0.2$ in the region in common between $A$ and $B$.

The event (set)  $(A\cup B)^c$ is the **complement** of the union of $A$ and $B$. So it is the region which is **outside** both $a$ and $B$, it is the rest of the world. The probability of that is $0.5$. Write $0.5$ somewhere in that region.

We want the probability of being in $A$ or $B$ but not in both. That region is made up of two parts, neither of which has yet been counted in. Call the probability of being in that split region $x$. Then
$$0.2+0.5+x=1,$$
because the probability of landing *somewhere* is $1$. Now we can find $x$.

**Another way:** Because the probability of the "rest of the world" is $0.5$, the probability of $A\cupB$ is $1-0.5$, which is $0.5$.

The part in both $A$ and $B$ has probability $0.2$. So the probability of being in $A$ or $B$ but **not** both is $0.5-0.2$.